# Characters.Insert Method (Excel) limits text to 255 characters

Tags: vba, excel

It is really impossible to append more than 255 chars into a single cell by VBA macro in MS Excel?

Sample code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestSub()
  Dim L As Long
'  Const str = "1" & vbLf
  Dim i As Integer
  Range("A1").ClearContents
  Range("A1").WrapText = True
  For i = 1 To 260  ' any number greatest than 255
    L = Range("A1").Characters.Count
    Debug.Print L
    Range("A1").Characters(L + 1, 1).Insert ("A")
  Next i
End Sub
```

*Added:*
It is important to save previous formatting of chars in cell.

Comment: Excel 2013 - there is no documented limits: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839171.aspx

Comment: If you are trying to append an `A` to the value in `Range("A1")` then just do that and bypass this `Characters.Insert` construct. Instead use: `Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value & "A"`. You can iterate through this line for as long as you wish. No limits here (tested).

Comment: I need to append text with different char formatting: aaaa**bbb**_ccc_ in single cell

Comment: What sample string are you working with?

Comment: As per [specification](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f) a cell can hold 32,767 characters. However, I've tried your code and it does error out at 256 using *Insert* property. Referencing the *Range Object* correctly removes the error but it is still limited to 255. I guess the limitation is within the *Character* property and not the cell character limit.

Comment: @L42 It seems that it true

Comment: @L42 I have to disagree. Maybe it is due to different Excel Versions, but it seems that I cannot reproduce the error you are experiencing. My Excel Version is 2016 64-bit and the below posted code runs without errors (inserting more than 255 characters into a cell and using the `Characters` method to format more than 255 characters).

Comment: Maybe... Now I trying this on Excel 2016 32bit 16.0.6868.2060

Answer (score 1):

The following code will write 500 `A` into cell `A1`. Afterwards, every other `A` will be formatted bold.

```
Public Sub tmpSO()

For i = 1 To 500
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value & "A"
Next i

For i = 1 To 500
    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
Next i

End Sub
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Note: your code won't work because you are trying to insert a character **after** `L + 1`. Yet, your string is currently only `L` long and **not** `L + 1`. Once you have inserted another `A` you will have `L + 1` characters in that cell. But not yet. So, if you are using your code with `Range("A1").Characters(L, 1).Insert ("A")` then it will work.

### Edit#1:

The following code has been tested and correctly inserts 500 `A` into cell `A1`. Furthermore, some of the `A` will be formatted bold.

```
Sub TestSub()
    Dim i As Integer

    Range("A1").ClearContents
    Range("A1").WrapText = True
    Range("A1").Font.Bold = False

    For i = 1 To 500
        Range("A1").Characters(i, 1).Insert ("A")
    Next i
    For i = 1 To 500 Step 10
        Range("A1").Characters(i, 3).Font.Bold = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't had described full problem first, sorry for that. I need to save previous text formatting in cell before append new.

Comment: Hmmm, @Ralph, code with `Range("A1").Characters(L, 1).Insert ("A")`  instead `L+1` doesn't append char, but replacing it

Comment: @StayAtHome sorry, but it seems I cannot reproduce the problem you are having. The above code works just fine on my computer (as it should) and **appends** an `A` to the end. Hence, I have in the end 500 `A` in cell `A1`.

Comment: how about `Range("A1").Characters.Count` ? Your code add only 255 chars in my Excel 2016 and raise exception in  Excel 2010 :(

Comment: I don't see the point in counting the characters when I know them to be of length `i` in the above code example. But yo can certainly do so.

Comment: But that is the main point: `Characters.Count` *does not equal* to `i` ! Just try to check it!

Comment: I wasn't aware that your `Characters.Count` method is failing. Maybe that's a new question! Yet, the above problem is about getting more than 255 characters into a cell. Still, if your `Characters.Count` is not updated yet then simply force Excel to recalculate the character count for that cell before getting it. Insert `Range("A1").Parent.Calculate` just before getting `L = Range("A1").Characters.Count`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112148/discussion-between-stayathome-and-ralph).

Comment: I tested this coded in 2003-2016 32bit and 2016 64bit. None of them put more than 255 characters in the cell.

Comment: Yes. `Characters.count` works fine also with more 255 chars, which added manually. But it looks like a bug in`Characters.Insert`.

Comment: It's a longstanding, if unacknowledged, issue. If you need to preserve formatting, I suggest you copy to Word, do the additions there, then copy and paste back.

Comment: Both StayAtHome and Rory is right. I can't insert beyond 255 characters as well. I am on 2016 here.

Answer (score 0):

*question changed with this additional comment*
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4742533/stayathome
*will return and update this*

*initial answer*

You can format the partial  string using *characters*.

Code below appends your sample string to test string (300 characters long), then makes the last three italic, the three before that bold.

```
Sub LikeThis()
Dim StrIn As String

StrIn = "aaaabbbccc"

[a1] = Application.Rept("xyz", 100)

[a1].Value2 = [a1].Value2 & StrIn

[a1].Characters(Len([a1]) - 5, 3).Font.Bold = True
[a1].Characters(Len([a1]) - 2, 3).Font.Italic = True

End Sub
```

Comment: No, previous formatting not saved. :( Try to comment line `'[a1] = Application.Rept("xyz", 100)` and run your code second time

Comment: Yes, you added that clarification as a comment above while I was posting. I will come back later and update.